# What is the difference between "guess an answer", "guess at an answer" and "guess an answer right"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Tell me please the difference between the following sentences.

> I **guessed** one answer in the exam.
>
> I **guessed** one answer **right** in the exam.
>
> I **guessed at** one answer in the exam.

Can the first sentence mean the same as the second one? If not, then what is the difference between the first and the third sentence?

Comment: The second means that you now know that your answer was right. You could say either of the other two when you don't yet know whether you guessed right or not. They both mean much the same thing.

Comment: But the first sentence can also mean "guess one answer right" can't it?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope The first and third are basically equivalent. It's an ambiguous sentence. It could mean "guess one answer right," but it could also mean "guess one answer wrong." It could mean you were certain on all the other answers and guessed just one, or that you left all the other answers blank and guessed just one.